# ¿Como detecto la pulsación de una tecla? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un proyecto WPF C# con .NET FRAMEWORK el asunto es que no me permite poder detectar la tecla ya que tengo esto como vistas:

- **MainWindow.xaml**
- **Views/UserControl.xaml**

Ahora yo en mi MainWindow, llamo al usercontrol y lo muestro.

Traté de incluir código en el UserControl, pero no funciona hasta que me situaba en algun objeto clickeable de mi UserControl. No puedo poner el código en mi MainWindow porque esta se pretende utilizar por varios UserControls distintos.

Hay alguna forma de realizar esto conservando el UserControl sin tener que cambiar este a Window para poder programar esto?

Adjunto código mainwindow.xaml:

```
    <DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Operaciones">
            <MenuItem Header="_Generar Etiquetas MP"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <views:UserControl Width="auto"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Adjunto codigo de UserControl.xaml

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="LISTADO DE CÓDIGOS ESCANEADOS" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <ListBox Name="listBox" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MaxHeight="393">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Juan, Edad: 25</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Carlos, Edad: 22</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Juan, Edad: 25</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Carlos, Edad: 22</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Juan, Edad: 25</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Carlos, Edad: 22</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Juan, Edad: 25</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Carlos, Edad: 22</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: Juan, Edad: 25</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Persona: María, Edad: 30</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Fila 1: Botón 1 -->
            <Button x:Name="btnReiniciar" Content="REINICIAR" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10 10 10 10" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>

            <!-- Fila 2: Botón 2 -->
            <Button x:Name="btn" Content="GENERAR" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10 10 10 5" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a a SOes por favor revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas la dinámica del sitio. ¿Podrías colocar todo el código fuente mínimo necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfectamente puedes escuchar el evento de un Control_A en un Control_B, y para el caso del `MainWindow` es especialmente fácil ya que siempre puedes acceder a la instancia con `App.Current.MainWindow`

Entonces en tu `UserControl`:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    App.Current.MainWindow.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
}
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MainWindow_KeyDown");
}
```

Los eventos en WPS son una pila de funciones que se van acumulando (puedes tener muchas funciones asociadas a un evento), muy parecido a lo que es el `addEventListener` de Javascript. Y como en este caso es el `MainWindow` el que tendrá la función asociada, al desaparecer tu `UserControl` aun existirá esa referencia, por lo que lo correcto será eliminarla

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    App.Current.MainWindow.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    this.Unloaded += UserControl1_Unloaded;
}
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MainWindow_KeyDown");
}
private void UserControl1_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainWindow.KeyDown -= MainWindow_KeyDown;
}
```

Comment: Una consulta, ahora ya mi Window no es MainWindow, ya que se implementó una navegabilidad y cada UserControl se muestra en una etiqueta `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentChildView}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="20" Background="Red"/>` con unos radio buttons se selecciona el UserControl a mostrar pero no me está reconociendo el PreviewKeyDown que tenía antes. este es el nombre de mi nueva Window `<Window x:Class="MainView">`

Comment: No entiendo, si no te reconoce el evento como sigue activo ??? Tendría que ver el código para poder responderte. Genera un [MCVE] y crea una nueva pregunta

Comment: Perdon, traté de incluir aca el codigo pero los caracteres son muy pocos. en breve subo una nueva pregunta

Comment: estuve viendo un código que al cargar ese UserControl
`this.Loaded += UserControl_Loaded;`
Que utiliza `Window.GetWindow(this);` en ese metodo UserControl_loaded

Ahora para poder desactivarlo en el unload me faltaba solo eso y de momento está funcionando muchisimas gracias de igual manera y perdon jeje.

Comment: @Cbr2022 Que bueno que hayas solucionado el problema. Suerte con el proyecto!!